# How to invert the Y-Axis control of the camera view when pressing "R" "R"

Tags: 3d-view, camera

When I am in the camera viewport and press "R" "R" to rotate the camera. I get this type of cursor.

[image: Cursor]

[image: Camera View]

When looking around, my control is inverted (up goes down, down goes up). How do I change this?

Comment: i also have a mac but i never saw this type of cursor and i cannot reproduce that. What add-ons did you install?

Comment: @Chris My mistake, the first part is irrelevant to my question. Alt+Command+0 on my Mac will set the camera view to the current 3D Viewport View. I do not believe this is 3rd party or a changed preference. Once in camera view, pressing R R with the camera selected will let you move the camera around based on it's location. It's good for making small changes.

Comment: @Chris To reproduce it go into camera view, select the camera and press R twice. It's the "trackball rotation" cursor, you also get it if you have any object selected and press R twice. [Blender Manual > Trackball Rotation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/rotate.html#trackball-rotation)